# How can I use photoswipe 5 in Angular 13

Tags: angular

I want to use new [photoswipe](https://photoswipe.com/) 5 lib with Angular 13, but not get the imports to work.

ERROR: Cannot find module 'photoswipe/lightbox' or its corresponding type declarations.ts

[image]

On their homepage they have samples for plain javascirpt, vue, react, but not with angular.
Any idea what is to do to get it work?

Thanks

Reproduce the problem

1. install angular cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

2. create new angular app

```
ng new ng-photoswipe --style scss --routing false
```

3. check if app is running

```
cd ng-photoswipe
npm start
```

4. install photoswipe

```
npm install photoswipe --save
```

5. add sample code

replace html code in app.component.html with

```html
<div class="pswp-gallery pswp-gallery--single-column" id="gallery--getting-started">
  <a
    href="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/2/img-2500.jpg"
    data-pswp-width="1669"
    data-pswp-height="2500"
    target="_blank">
    <img src="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/2/img-200.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
  <a
    href="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/7/img-2500.jpg"
    data-pswp-width="1875"
    data-pswp-height="2500" data-cropped="true" target="_blank">
    <img src="https://cdn.photoswipe.com/photoswipe-demo-images/photos/7/img-200.jpg" alt="" />
  </a>
</div>
```

replace ts code in app.component.ts with

```js
import { AfterContentInit, Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';

import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/lightbox';
import PhotoSwipe from 'photoswipe';
import 'photoswipe/style.css';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

  ngAfterContentInit(): void {
    this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
      const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
        gallery: '#gallery--getting-started',
        children: 'a',
        pswpModule: PhotoSwipe,
      });

      lightbox.init();
    });
  }
}
```

because we have not typeings add photoswipe.d.ts next to app.component.ts with code

```js
declare module 'photoswipe';
```

6. try run again

```
npm start
```

I get the following error during build in console

```
Error: src/app/app.component.ts:3:32 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'photoswipe/lightbox' or its corresponding type declarations.

3 import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/lightbox';
```

7. more infos

exports in packages.json from PhotoSwipe =>
https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/blob/master/package.json

```json
"exports": {
    ".": "./dist/photoswipe.esm.js",
    "./lightbox": "./dist/photoswipe-lightbox.esm.js",
    "./dist/photoswipe.css": "./dist/photoswipe.css",
    "./photoswipe.css": "./dist/photoswipe.css",
    "./style.css": "./dist/photoswipe.css"
  },
```

My questions:

- Why import is not working here?
- What is the difference to other frameworks like vue, react or plain javascript imports? (see photoswipe examples)
- Has the lib author something to do?

In putting together this example, I solved my own problem.
Add missing typeings and import css solved this issue.

https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/1881

Comment: @zedL, Could you please help me how did you modify the css and what version are you using? by default I get fullscreen and it is not closing the popup when clicked on close button. :|

Comment: > angular.json => "styles": [
              "node_modules/photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ]

Comment: at the git hub issue I added a full working example https://github.com/dimsemenov/PhotoSwipe/issues/1881

Answer (score 1):

> The Below solution works for me

[PhotoSwipe Git Hub Link](https://github.com/AbdullahPariyani/ng-photoswipe)

**Step 1: Install   photoswipe**

- "photoswipe": "^5.2.4" - This version I have installed in my code

**Step 2: Added photoswipe.d.ts**

- Add photoswipe.d.ts file in your src/app/**HERE** folder and add below two lines
- *declare module 'photoswipe';*
- *declare module 'photoswipe/lightbox';*

**Step 3: Add style in the angular.json file**

- [image]

Step 4: Create your angular component

- Create your angular component and add the below code in your ts file

TS File

[image]

HTML File
[image]

You can access the below class in your SCSS files for custom designs

```
    :host {
    .pswp-gallery {
        background-color: white;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
    }

    img {
        height: 18rem;
        object-fit: inherit;
        object-position: inherit;
        padding: 5px;
        border-radius: 15px;
        min-width: 25rem;

    }

    .pswp-gallery {
        display: flex;
        overflow-x: auto;
        /* Enable horizontal scrolling if there are more images */
    }

    /* Style each image container */
    .pswp-gallery a {
        margin-right: 5px;
        /* Adjust the spacing between images */
        flex-shrink: 0;
        /* Prevent images from shrinking */
    }

    /* Remove the underline from anchor tags */
    .pswp-gallery a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* Optional: Add hover effect */
    .pswp-gallery a:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**> The above solution I have implemented in ionic 7, and also in angular 13. it works fine**

**> Documentation link: https://photoswipe.com/**

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on React, had to change the component I was importing that package in from .tsx to .jsx

There should be a better fix though